# Go to new file in vim

Tags: vim

In vim, I can type 'gf' to go to the file path under the cursor but if that file doesn't exist, I get an error.

Is there a way to open up a new file named with the word under the cursor?  Ideally I'd like this buffer to open up in a new tab.

**Edit** `noremap gf :tabe <cfile><CR>` is a good suggestion but I'm hoping there's also a way to implement this mapping AND take advantage of the `suffixesadd` setting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the help of `:help gf`

```
If you do want to edit a new file, use:
        :e <cfile>
To make gf always work like that:
        :map gf :e <cfile><CR>
```

If you want to open it in a new tab you can change the `:e` to `:tabe`, so you would get

```
noremap gf :tabe <cfile><CR>
```

---

`<cfile>` is replaced by the path underneath the cursor.

---

The following is a function that tries the normal `<c-w>gf` (open file under the cursor in a new tab, respecting `'suffixesadd'` and checking to see if the file exists) and if that fails just open the file under the cursor in a new tab.

```
function Gf()
    try
        exec "normal! \<c-w>gf"
    catch /E447/
        tabedit <cfile>
    endtry
endfunction

noremap gf :call Gf()<CR>
```

Comment: `noremap gf :tabe <cfile><CR>` looks good.  Is there a way to take advantage of the 'suffixesadd' setting using this mapping?

Comment: @chishaku I added a function that tries to use the normal `<c-w>gf` which will respect `'suffixesadd' `. However since `'suffixesadd' ` is a comma separated list it can't know which one to open if there is more than one suffix in the list. If you want that you can add it yourself.

Comment: @FDinoff, the `noremap gf :tabe <cfile><CR>` seems good, but it puts cursor into NerdTree, do you have solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `:e <filename>` to edit the file, regardless of whether it exists or not.

Comment: I'm aware of this command but it doesn't have the same convenience of 'gf' that I'm going for.